# Trouble looping lists and writing to a file

Tags: python, file, list, for-loop, indexing

Im writing a mapeditor for a game and im having trouble writing the information to a file

so im writing a copy function that will take the rect your mouse is over and copy it to another place keeping the image path but giving it new coords and appending it to a surface list

i got that to work but when i try to write it to a file i have trouble

here is the for loop for writing it:

```
for index, item in enumerate(self.surface_list):
     posfi.write('SURFACE:%s:%s:ground%s\n' % (self.surface_paths[index], item[1], item[2]))
```

the problem is there are more surfaces(rects) than images (becuase i copied the image) so at `self.surface_paths[index]` there are more rects than images so the list index goes out of range

i tried adding this `if index < len(self.surface_paths):` but that makes it so it only writes the first 2 rects to the file because im using 2 different images

can anyone tell me how i can write the rects to the file with out the path list going out of range

thank you!

Comment: It sounds like your self.surface_list should have same number of dimensions as the self.surface_paths but it doesn't. It's not related to file IO but to data manipulation.

Comment: so when i copy the rect in surface list i should copy the image name too

Comment: Instead of make `surface_list` a list of lists of points (which I'm guessing you're doing), make it a list of lists of lists of points so that the indices used for it and `surface_paths` will stay in sync.

Comment: surface list is a list of lists that contain an obj with a height and a width and a x and y coord

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but if you want to be able to access `surface_list` and/or `surface_paths` after the current function has completed, have you considered using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)?

```
import cPickle as pickle #cPickle is faster than pickle
#To save
savePth = '' #Save file path
f = open(savePth, 'w') #w for "write"
pickle.dump(self.surface_list, f)
f.close()
```

Now your variable is saved in whatever file `savePth` pointed to. To load:

```
import cPickle as pickle
#To load
f = open(savePth, 'r') #r for "read"
self.surface_list = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```